# How to query jTable from jComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jcombobox

I have some data in a jTable and want to query a category (Chairs, Desks, etc.) with a drop down box and a search button. I want to have the user select a category, such as Desks, and click the jButton Available Furniture, and be shown a message like: "There are 5 desks. They are Small Office Desk, Large Office Desk, etc." How can I do this?

Here is a picture of the program with the data so you can see what I mean:

jTable with some information and furniture categories

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzGJU.png]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way to do this is to just "filter" the table when you do your search by the keyword.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example.

You will just need to modify the code to get the search keyword from a combo box instead of a text field.

Comment: Thank you, I will read this as filtering would be a nice option to have also. But for this particular program I would like to have the user be able to search from the combo box and have a message pop up to show at least how many items are available within the given category. Do you know how to do it? I've searched online a lot before asking this question, but I can't seem to find anywhere that will explain how to do what I want to do, even though it seems like a simple enough concept.

Comment: So you filter the table then count the rows left in the table. Or you just write a loop to look at all the rows in the table and then add 1 every time you find the category you are searching for.

Comment: I see the logic behind what you're suggesting, thank you for this! By any chance would you be able to show me the code of how to do this exactly? I don't know how to do it as I'm very much a beginner, but I would say that I am aware that the Table1's columnCount would be 1 to select the Category column. That is about all I know, I don't know how to write the code exactly to do what you have suggested unfortunately, but if you could show me how to do it I would learn it and see how to do it for the future.

Comment: So you use the `getValueAt(...)` method of the table and see if the value is what you want. Writing a loop is basic Java that you need to learn on your own.